# What is the default user agent when using 'wget' on Linux?

Tags: linux, wget

What is the default user agent when using the 'wget' command on Linux. I'm not trying to fake out a website when it's being used, I simply want to know what appears in the Apache logs. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change it with command `--user-agent=agent-string`.

[The man page says](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-user_002dagent-100):

> Wget normally identifies as ‘Wget/version’, version being the current
>   version number of Wget.

Answer (score 7):

From the manual

> The http protocol allows the clients to identify themselves using a
>   User-Agent header field. This enables distinguishing the www software,
>   usually for statistical purposes or for tracing of protocol
>   violations. Wget normally identifies as ‘**Wget/version**’, version being
>   the current version number of Wget.

source http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Answer (score 0):

While the man page says it is `Wget/version` (like [others](https://superuser.com/a/495864/1077440) pointed out already), it is *currently* actually:

```
Wget/version (linux-gnu)
```

at least on Ubuntu.

To inspect the actual user agent being sent, you can add the `-d` option to your `wget` call.